# Grouping in SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

Suppose I have a Table such that:

```
|ID  | product |orderid | brand |number of product cust ord| 
|----|---------|--------|-------|--------------------------|   
| 1  |   123   |   111  |   br  |        1                 |
|----|---------|--------|-------|--------------------------| 
| 1  |   234   |   111  |   br  |        1                 |
|----|---------|--------|-------|--------------------------|
| 1  |   345   |   333  |   br  |        1                 |
|----|---------|--------|-------|--------------------------|
| 2  |   123   |   211  |   br  |        1                 |
|----|---------|--------|-------|--------------------------|
| 2  |   456   |   212  |   br  |        2                 |
|----|---------|--------|-------|--------------------------|
| 3  |   567   |   213  |   br  |        1                 |
|----|---------|--------|-------|--------------------------|
```

What I'd like to do is group them as:

```
|ID  | brand   |number of product cust ord| 
|----|---------|--------------------------|   
| 1  |   br    |        3                 |
|----|---------|--------------------------| 
| 2  |   br    |        4                 |
|----|---------|--------------------------|
```

further to that i'd like to classify them and tried a case...when but can't seem to get it right.

if ID purchases more than 3 unique products and orders more than twice- i'd like to call them a frequent buyer (in the above example, ID '1' would be a 'frequent buyer'), if the average number of products they purchase is higher than the average number of that product sold - i'd like to call them a 'merchant', else just a purchaser.

Comment: Your description and your desired results have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Essentially we're trying to count the number of products a customer ordered of a particular brand.  So we don't necessarily need to keep their productid or orderid..but for each customer we want to know how many items they're purchasing in a particular brand category.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is one way that you could do it. Note that according to the description you gave, buyers could be constantly being reclassified between 'Merchant' and 'Purchaser' as the average goes up and down. That might not be what you want.

```
With cte As (
    Select ID,
        Brand,
        DistinctOrders = Count(Distinct OrderID), -- How many separate orders by this customer for the brand?
        DistinctProducts = Count(Distinct Product), -- How many different products by this customer for the brand?
        [number of product cust ord] = Sum(CountOfProduct), -- Total number of items by this customer for the brand. 
        AverageCountOfProductPerBuyer = 
            Sum(Sum(CountOfProduct)) Over () * 1.0 / (Select Count(*) From (Select Distinct ID, Brand From #table) As tbl) 
            -- Average number of items per customer (for all customers) for this brand
      From #table
      Group By ID, Brand)
Select ID, Brand, DistinctOrders, DistinctProducts, [number of product cust ord],
    IsFrequentBuyer = iif(DistinctOrders > 1 And DistinctProducts > 2, 'Frequent Buyer', NULL),
    IsMerchant = iif(AverageCountOfProductPerBuyer < [number of product cust ord], 'Merchant', 'Purchaser')
  From cte;
```

This query could be written without the common-table expression, but was written this way to avoid defining expressions multiple times.

Note that I have the first ID as a 'Frequent Buyer' based on your description, so I'm assuming that when you say 'more than 3 unique products' you mean 3 or more. Likewise with two or more distinct orders.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I've renamed the last field to qty for brevity and called the table test1.

To get frequent flyers use below query. Note that I used >= instead of >. I changed this based on your example where ID 1 is a "frequent flyer" even though he only bought 3 products, not more than 3.

```
SELECT ID, count(distinct product) as DistinctProducts, count(distinct orderid) DistinctOrders
FROM test1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING count(distinct product)  >= 3 and count(distinct orderid) >= 2
```

Not sure if I understood the merchant logic correctly. Below is the query which will give you customers that on average purchased more than overall average of product for any given product.  There are none in the data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.ID
FROM 
(select ID, product, avg(qty) as AvgQty
FROM test1
GROUP BY ID, product) as c
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(select product, avg(qty) as AvgQty
FROM test1
GROUP BY product) p ON p.product = c.product
WHERE c.AvgQty > p.AvgQty;
```

To get "purchasers" do EXCEPT between all customer and the UNION of merchants and frequent buyers:

```
select distinct ID from test1

EXCEPT 

(SELECT ID FROM (
select ID, count(distinct product) as DistinctProducts, count(distinct orderid) DistinctOrders
FROM test1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING count(distinct product)  >= 3 and count(distinct orderid) >= 2) t

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT c.ID
FROM 
(select ID, product, avg(qty) as AvgQty
FROM test1
GROUP BY ID, product) as c
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(select product, avg(qty) as AvgQty
FROM test1
GROUP BY product) p ON p.product = c.product
WHERE c.AvgQty > p.AvgQty
);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but I was getting duplicates in the frequents and merchants table, but I was able to work that out :)